# Lua Metatable Inconsistency

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

I'm having trouble understanding why there is a difference in behavior of the `__index` metamethod between these to examples:

```
A = { __index = A }   
function A:speak()
    print("I'm an A")
end
An_A = setmetatable({},A)
An_A:speak()
```

Will raise the following error: `lua: l.lua:8: attempt to call method 'speak' (a nil value)`

Whilst

```
B = { __index = function(t,key)  return B[key] end }
function B:speak()
    print("I'm an B")
end
An_B = setmetatable({},B)
An_B:speak()
```

Will perform as expected, outputting `I'm an B`.

---

In trying to understand why this was the case I read [this](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html) section of PiL. It states that:

> The use of the __index metamethod for inheritance is so common that
>   Lua provides a shortcut. Despite the name, the __index metamethod does
>   not need to be a function: It can be a table, instead. When it is a
>   function, Lua calls it with the table and the absent key as its
>   arguments. **When it is a table, Lua redoes the access in that table.**

My understanding of this is that in the snippet involving 'A', `__index = A` cause the access to be done in the table `A` (as per the boldened segmenet of the above quote). If this is the case I don't understand why the function associated with the key `"speak"` isn't found. In an attempt to try fix this, I decided to implement the function approach in the `B` snippet, which returns the value associated with `key` in `B`, and it worked. Surely `__index = A` and (adapted from `B`) `__index = function(t,key) return A[key] end` have the same effect.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's happening in your first example is that `A.__index == nil`. When you created 'A' on your first line here:

```
A = { __index = A }
```

The right-hand side of the the assignment 'A' evaluates to `nil` since it doesn't exist yet at this point. As a result, later on when you set the metatable here:

```
An_A = setmetatable({},A)
```

it really ends up doing something akin to this:

```
An_A = setmetatable({}, {__index = nil} )
```

To get it to work the way you want, you have to make sure `__index` isn't `nil`. For example, assign it after table construction:

```
A = {}
A.__index = A

function A:speak()
  print("I'm an A")
end
An_A = setmetatable({},A)
An_A:speak()              --> outputs I'm an A
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, it didn't occur to me this would happen, I had assumed it would be like some other languages where something such as `f = lambda n: f(n)` is valid. cheers :)

Comment: @HennyH: `f = function(n) return f(n) end` is fine in lua for the same reason. The equivalent failing python is `d = {"__index": d}`, but python will `NameError`

Comment: @Eric I suppose any recursive function follows the same pattern.

Comment: It would actually work if you set `__index` to a function accessing A, which is similar to your python example, instead of using A directly: `A = { __index = function(t,k) return A[k] end }`. Because the function will look up A by name when it's called, and by that time it will have the right value.